# Getting exception while build in junit test execution

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, junit5

> Task :test
>   Exception in thread "Thread-24" java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'traceApplicationContextRefreshedListener': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.stopAndReleaseReactiveWebServer(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:174)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.onClose(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:93)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1023)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:937)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'traceApplicationContextRefreshedListener': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:208)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:224)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1012)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:338)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:333)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ReactorSleuth.contextRefreshed(ReactorSleuth.java:145)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ReactorSleuth.lambda$null$2(ReactorSleuth.java:124)
>           at reactor.core.publisher.MonoLift.subscribe(MonoLift.java:42)
>           at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1174)
>           at reactor.ipc.netty.tcp.BlockingNettyContext.shutdown(BlockingNettyContext.java:152)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer.stop(NettyWebServer.java:123)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.stopAndReleaseReactiveWebServer(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:170)
>           ... 3 more

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple of reasons for that possibly which I can recollect looking at this issue:

1. Setting the right path to the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, updating your `PATH` variable and restarting your eclipse / STS IDE whichever you're using.
2. The other could be multiple Tomcat instances are open at the same time when you're trying to run your JUnit test cases. You could close all of those instances and open just one to get this sorted.

Kindly cross-check these and let me know it helps!

Comment: I am using springboot 2.0 with webflux. I am not running tomcat explicitly. Also, home path is set properly

Comment: @Soni I am getting the exactly same problem. Did you find any solution for this trouble? thanks a lot